# Acessar função IIFE no escopo global

Tags: javascript, dom

Galera, estou fazendo uns testes em JavaScript, e preciso acessar uma função IIFE no escopo global, pois o elemento está sendo criado dentro dele e ele faz uma execução `onclick` chamando uma função, porém essa função está dentro do escopo IIFE.

```
(function(){

function addEle(){
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', '#');
    a.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteEle(1)');
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Elemento qualquer'));
    document.body.appendChild();
}

function deleteEle(pos){
    //do....
}

})();
```

Quando o usuário clica no botão é chamado a função:

> deleteEle()

que está no escopo local e o JavaScript não reconhece.

Answer (score 1):

Até onde sei, funções dentro de escopo local são inacessíveis do lado de fora. Em vista disso, o que você poderia fazer era criar um `addEventListener` ao elemento em vez de um `onclick`:

**Veja:**

```js
(function(){

   addEle(); // chama a função que irá criar o elemento
   function addEle(){
       var a = document.createElement('a');
       a.setAttribute('href', '#');
   //    a.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteEle(1)');
       a.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Elemento qualquer'));
       document.body.appendChild(a);
       a.addEventListener("click", function(){ deleteEle(1) });
   }

   function deleteEle(pos){
       //do....
       console.log(pos);
   }

})();
```